# How to check registered name of Excel ComAddIns?

Tags: excel, vba, com

I am reading this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/01/15/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice.aspx) and in the 4th paragraph opening line it says:

> "From the VBA code, you can see that my add-in is registered as
>   “ExcelAddinService”."

How do you check the registered name of the ComAddIn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author knows that because he registered it under that name. You can find out all of your COM add-ins' registered names using the following:

```
Sub PrintAddinNames()
    Dim addin As COMAddIn
    For Each addin In Application.COMAddIns
        Debug.Print addin.progID
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a way without code, but that works too.

Comment: Tools menu - Addins. Alt + T, then I.